# How to match an area code in MS access

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 area codes I need to match in my database
the area code is 214 and 927
I am using the LIKE clause

```
 select * test where phone like "*972*"
```

I believe if 972 is anywhere in the phone number it will be matched. I need 972 to be only matched with the area code.

The phone formats can be (###) ### - ####
or ##########

Is this possible to do in access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from test where left(phone, 3) = "972" -- for ########## format
```

Or:

```
select * from test where left(phone, 5) = "(972)" -- for (###) ### - #### format
```

Comment: I believe that if your phone number field is indexed, a LIKE will used the index if you are matching on the beginning of the field, so LIKE "(972)*" or LIKE "927*" should be more efficient than testing the result of the Left function.